# Node.js API with express & mysql - Apply search parameter only if set, equal and like combined

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

I want to be able to also LIKE '%first_name%' search for one of the parameters. In specific for column 'first_name'

That's the url that return me the desired value:

```
http://localhost:4001/api/v1/users/?active=0&title=mr&first_name=alexa
```

But I would also like to get result when doing this:

```
http://localhost:4001/api/v1/users/?active=0&title=mr&first_name=alex
```

That's my query:

```
router.get('/?', function(req, res, next) {

    var title = req.query.title;
    var active = req.query.active;
    var first_name = req.query.first_name;

    var sql = "SELECT * from users";
    var existingParams = ["title", "active", "first_name"].filter(field => req.query[field]);

    if (existingParams.length) { 
        sql += ' WHERE ';
        sql += existingParams.map(field => `${field} = ?`).join(" AND ");
    }   

    connection.query(
        sql, 
        existingParams.map(field => req.query[field]), 
        function (error, results, fields) {
            res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
    });

});
```

How do I need to alter the script?

Answer (score 0):

```html
sql += existingParams.map(field => {

  if (field === 'first_name') {
    return `${field} like %?%`;
  } else {
    return `${field} = ?`;
  }
}).join(" AND ");
```

Try this

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work ... I'm getting sql error: sql "SELECT * from users WHERE title = 'mr' AND active = '0' AND first_name like %'alexa'%"

Comment: ... I probably need to adjust this part: existingParams.map(field => req.query[field]) in the connection.query() ...